# Making Web-scraping program using jupyter notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' even though its installed:

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

Please help been stuck on this for hours now?

[image: Jupyter Notebook output]

Terminal saying requirements already satisfied

[image]

Comment: Hi Senthol, please try and put text in text format (probably in code blocks) instead of as images - images are harder for people to parse, and may turn people away from helping with your question. If all the information is readily available and copy-pastable, it helps with the issue investigation.

Comment: Is the Python installation you're using to run the Notebook the same as the one in which you installed the package? (Hint: It probably isn't)

Comment: @AMC thank you for this i checked and this fixed the problem! Thank you! i downloaded pip install requests directly in the jupyter cell.

Comment: @Oliver.R Hey thank you for your suggestion i will keep that in mind. This was more of a file path problem hence images.